# First order PLL power consumption

Tags: rf, pll

For a system level project I want to estimate the impact having a single vs. multiple PLLs.

Is there a first order estimate that relates power, jitter (total integrated phase noise) and possibly tuning/range and settling time?

For example, one spec is a tuning range of about 800 MHz around 2 GHz and less than 300fs jitter, settling in ~200ns.

I browsed through some datasheets but I am looking more for a first-order model that I can plug into system equations.

Comment: puh that is a simple equation that you hope to describe something pretty complex. Frankly, there's so much technological variability in how to implement a >1 octave PLL that I doubt there can be a general formula. I'd split my PLL into its components, fix the technology of these and generate estimates for those.

Comment: If you want low phasenoise (low jitter) then the resistors have to be LOW values. That requires the consumption of power. Assume 10 milliAmps. Plus whatever the VCO needs.